# How to get multiple node element types into one variable from XML

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am trying to have my PHP code call multiple different node type from an XML doc, I was wondering if this is possible.

php example:

```
$categoryNames = 'CLEANINGCHEMICALS' and 'CLEANINGACCESSORIES';
$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName($categoryNames);
```

I have gotten it to work with JavaScript although php I am struggling with, here is my javascript example:

```
var xmlNode = "CLEANINGACCESSORIES" && "CLEANINGCHEMICALS";
records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(xmlNode);
```

Here is my XML example of what I mean by different node types:

`<CLEANINGCHEMICALS>` & `<CLEANINGACCESSORIES>` & `<WASHROOMSUPPLIES>`

```
<CATALOG>
    <CLEANINGCHEMICALS>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/thumbnails/X22318 Wettex Large Roll.jpg</IMAGE>
        <BIGIMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/X22318 Wettex Large Roll.jpg</BIGIMAGE>
        <TITLE>Wettex Large Roll</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>x22318 - Wettex Large Roll</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </CLEANINGCHEMICALS>
    <CLEANINGACCESSORIES>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Accessories/thumbnails/1204321 R2 plus with Divermite bottle.jpg</IMAGE>
        <BIGIMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Accessories/1204321 R2 plus with Divermite bottle.jpg</BIGIMAGE>
        <TITLE>R2 plus with Divermite bottle</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>1204321 - R2 plus with Divermite bottle</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-accessories</CATEGORY>
    </CLEANINGACCESSORIES>
    <WASHROOMSUPPLIES>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Accessories/thumbnails/1204323 R3 plus with Divermite bottle.jpg</IMAGE>
        <BIGIMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Accessories/1204323 R3 plus with Divermite bottle.jpg</BIGIMAGE>
        <TITLE>R3 plus with Divermite bottle</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>1204323 - R3 plus with Divermite bottle</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-accessories</CATEGORY>
    </WASHROOMSUPPLIES>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: look into XPATH's`local-name()`, which lets you treat the tagname as a string property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPath](http://php.net/domxpath) is your friend here.

---

#### Example:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$x = $xpath->query('//CLEANINGCHEMICALS | //CLEANINGACCESSORIES');
```

---

[DOMXpath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), same as [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). The query itself returns a union of the two node sets.